# Javascript hours ahead or behind now

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am trying to calculate the number of hours between now and some time in the future or the past.  If the date/time is in the future it will be a positive number , if in the past a negative number.

I have tried

```
    var hours_away = Math.abs(flight_date.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 3600000;
    hours_away = parseInt(hours_away);
```

However if the flight_date variable is before or after now.getTime() the number is always returned positive.

Can anyone help with a date diff example that produces the right positive or negative result?

Comment: Just lose the `Math.abs()` call - suppressing the sign is exactly what this function does!

Answer (score 1):

`Math.abs` means absolute value.

Absolute value always return a positive number.

`x = |-5| // x is actually 5.`

You can read from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

> The Math.abs() function returns the absolute value of a number

Answer (score 0):

You are using math.abs which return absolute number (positive)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to get your flight hours in a valid string type, and then create a valid date object out of that string, then you can subtract flight time from the current time, if it's ahed of now, you will get a positive number.

Check the function bellow:

```js
// try changing the flight_time to see if this works or not

var flight_time  = '2018-10-28T20:20:30Z'; // assuming this is the flight time;
// now make a valid date format out of the given flight time;
var flight_hour = new Date(flight_time);
console.log(flight_hour)
var current_hour = new Date();
console.log(current_hour);

// now do the subtraction;
function calculate_hours() {
  var difference = ((flight_hour - current_hour) / 3600000).toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById('now').innerHTML = flight_hour.getHours();
  document.getElementById('difference').innerHTML = difference;
  console.log(difference) ;
}

calculate_hours();
```

```html
<p> Now: <span id='now'></span></p>
<p> Difference: <span id='difference'></span></p>
```